# Google Cloud Storage maximum access limits

Tags: google-cloud-storage

The system i am building is currently storing videos with **Google Cloud Storage**, my server will return the link from Google Cloud Storage which is used to play the video on mobile platforms. Is there a limit for how many user can access that link at the same time? . Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

All of the known limits for Cloud Storage are listed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas).  It says:

> There is no limit to reads of objects in a bucket, which includes reading object data, reading object metadata, and listing objects. Buckets initially support roughly 5000 object reads per second and then scale as needed.

So, no, there are effectively no limits to the number of concurrent downloads.

Comment: You can use case control to improve this technical limit